# How to control program termination in C

Tags: c, signals

A program called `server.c` terminates another program called `client.c` when I send a SIGINT (ctrl-c) to the server. My question is: How can I control the termination of my client? I want it to print something right before it exits.

I have tried catching the following signals but none of them are being caught:

```
sigaction(SIGINT, &newact, NULL);

sigaction(SIGQUIT, &newact, NULL);

sigaction(SIGTERM, &newact, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &newact, NULL);
```

Are there any other signals that might cause the program to terminate?

Comment: All those signals you tried catching are catchable, show the code what you tried.

Comment: Why does the server send signals to the client? Don't they communicate in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

With GCC family of C compilers, we can mark some functions to execute before and after main(). So some startup code can be executed before main() starts, and some cleanup code can be executed after main() ends.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Apply the constructor attribute to myStartupFun() so that it
    is executed before main() */
void myStartupFun (void) __attribute__ ((constructor));


/* Apply the destructor attribute to myCleanupFun() so that it
   is executed after main() */
void myCleanupFun (void) __attribute__ ((destructor));


/* implementation of myStartupFun */
void myStartupFun (void)
{
    printf ("startup code before main()\n");
}

/* implementation of myCleanupFun */
void myCleanupFun (void)
{
    printf ("cleanup code after main()\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

startup code before main()
hello
cleanup code after main()

Comment: `myStartupFun` works perfectly however `myCleanupFun` never outputs. Could there be a reason for this?

Comment: i believe both startup and cleanup functions will run.If there is no output one reason can be the compiler doesn't show any output after the end of the main function (maybe you are not using GCC compiler).